# computing the kernel of the multiplication endormophism

Tags: abstract-algebra

I would like to compute the kernel of the multiplication endomorphism $R[X,Y]\otimes_{R[X^2]} R[X,Y] \rightarrow R[X,Y]$ where $R$ is a commutative algebra. I know it is generated by the elements of the form $P\otimes 1 - 1 \otimes P$ but I cannot find if there is a more precise way to describe the kernel in this case.

Thanks in advance

Comment: It is the ideal generated by $X\otimes 1-1\otimes X$ and $Y\otimes 1-1\otimes Y$

Comment: Okay but it would be the same if we took the tensor over $R[X]$ right ? so what role is playing the $R[X^2]$ here ?

Comment: The kernel of $R[X,Y]\otimes_{R[X]} R[X,Y] \rightarrow R[X,Y]$  is the ideal generated by  $Y\otimes 1-1\otimes Y \qquad$ 
 ($R[X]$ and $R[X^2,Z]/(Z^2-X^2)$ are not the same)

Comment: ok my bad ! thanks for all the information

Comment: Sorry I meant $R[X^2,Z]/(Z^2-X^2)$ and $R[X]$ are the same, what is not the same is $R[X,Z]/(Z^2-X^2)\cong R[X] \otimes_{R[X^2]}R[X]$